# Как получить доступ к полю из CIL

Tags: c#, cil

Есть класс:

```
public class Test
{
   private string[] _array;

   public Test(int n)
   {
      _array = new string[n];
   }
   
   //return _array[i];
   public string Method(int i) 
   {
        var ownerType = this.GetType();
        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("test_method", 
                                                  typeof(string), 
                                                  new Type[] { typeof(int) },
                                                  ownerType );
        var generator = method.GetILGenerator();

        var arrayField = ownerType.GetField("_array", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, arrayField);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (string)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { i });
   }
}
```

При вызове `Method` исключение
`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Inner Exception: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`. Как мне подгрузить текущий инстанс класса так, чтобы его члены были доступны в DynamicMethod'е?

Comment: Что конкретно ты хочешь сделать в dynamic методе?

Comment: @Grundy `return _array[i]`

Comment: почему не воспользоваться `Expression` и `Compile`?

Comment: @Grundy такими способами я уже умею)

Comment: первым параметром `Invoke` принимает объект, `null` передается только в случае `static` методов. По сути тебе надо было просто `this` передать

Comment: @Grundy Не помогло( Всё равно та же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` неявно передается в качестве первого аргумента.

Таким образом у нового метода, на самом деле, **2 параметра**

```
new Type[] { ownerType, typeof(int) },
```

а также, при вызове нужно тоже передавать оба

```
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { this, i });
```